# PDF which is stored on Sharepoint will not open in MS Access Web Control on one machine only

Tags: ms-access, pdf, controls

I have a two controls on a MS Access Form. One is a hyperlink control and the other is a Web Browser Control.

The hyperlink is setup as such:  Is Hyperlink Yes -> Display as hyperlink Always, Hyperlink Target WebBrowser14 (which is the name of the aforementioned Web Browser Control.)

On everyone else machine the hyperlink opens in the web browser control.  But for some reason, for me only, the PDF opens in the Adobe Acrobat client on my machine.

Any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: Side note:  I just discovered that I am the only person with Adobe Acrobat X on my system.  I am also the only one with the PDF Maker plug-in associated with Access.  I tried disabling the plug-in but this did not help.  I am unable to remove it completely.  I will try to uninstall Adobe Acrobat X and see what happens.

Comment: Uninstalling Acrobat X did not help.  Still the same problem.

Comment: I logged on to my machine as another user and the PDF files opened in the Web Browser Control.  It appears to be an issue with a profile setting.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up completely uninstalling Adobe X Reader and Acrobat and reinstalling Reader.  This resolved the issue.  I wish I would have known where the setting was exactly instead of just uninstalling and reinstalling but was short on time.  If anyone comes across this and has an idea of the reg/application setting that caused this to happen, please let me know.  This was more of a work around than an actual solution.